# *Beginner *C confusing me with Warnings

Tags: c, struct, warnings

so I declared a float named price and when I try to compile it I get a waring that it would be a double, can someone tell me why C think that this is a double ?

B3N2.c:37: warning: format specifies type 'float *' but the argument has type 'double' [-Wformat]
                                        scanf("%f", la[i].preis);

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    struct Lager {
        char artikel[200];
        int anzahl;
        float preis;
    }  la[200];


    printf("Wilkommen bei Lagerverwaltung 97\n\n\nWas möchten sie tun ?\n");

    int exit = 0;
    int x,v;
    int f = 1;
    int i =  0;

    char ques;
    int end;
    do {
        printf("\n(1)Artikel hinzufügen\n(2)Artikel entnehmen.\n(3)Eintrag suchen.\n(4)Lager ausgeben.\n(5)Exit\n");
        scanf("%x",&x);

        switch (x) {
            case 1://add
                do {
                    printf("\nGebe den namen des Produkts an:  ");
                    scanf("%s", la[i].artikel);

                    printf("\nAnzahl der verfügbaren Produkte:  ");
                    scanf("%i", &la[i].anzahl);

                    printf("\ngib den preis des artikels an:  ");
                    scanf("%f", la[i].preis);

                    printf("\n\nWeiteres Produkt hinzufügen ? (J/N)");
                    scanf("%s", &ques);

                    switch (ques) {
                        case 'J':
                            v++;
                            f++;
                            break;
                        case 'N':
                            end = 1;
                            v = 0;
                            break;
                        default:
                            printf("Falsche Eingabe\n");
                            break;
                    }
                } while (end != 1);
                if (v >= 2) {
                    printf("Produkt wurde Erfolgreich hinzugefügt\n\n");
                }else {
                    printf("Produkte wurden Erfolgreich hinzugefügt\n\n");
                }
                break;
```

sorry for the dumb question but I tryed to fix it and now i'm totally Overwhelmed

Answer (score 0):

`scanf()` needs a *pointer* to the space (that is, the variable) where the scanned value will be stored. But your call hands over the *value* of `la[i].preis` which is a `float` that is cast automatically into a `double`.

Change your code to give the address of `la[i].preis` to `scanf()` by using the `&` operator like this:

```
scanf("%f", &la[i].preis);
```